# 2nd angular directive blank when 2 directives are on a page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have 2 directives created:

```
module WU_Tombstones.core.directives {
    export function publicOffersList(): ng.IDirective {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            scope: {},
            controller: WU_Tombstones.controllers.publicOffersController,
            controllerAs: 'offersCtl',
            templateUrl: '/desktopmodules/lrsweb/wu_tombstones/app/publicOffers/publicOffers.html',
            replace: false
        }
    }
    export function advisoryTransactionsList(): ng.IDirective {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            scope: {},
            controller: WU_Tombstones.controllers.advisoryTransactionsController,
            controllerAs: 'transCtl',
            templateUrl: '/desktopmodules/lrsweb/wu_tombstones/app/advisoryTransactions/advisoryTransactions.html',
            replace: false
        }
    } 
}
```

in my html I simply have these 2 elements:

```
<div ng-app="WU_Tombstones">
    <public-offers-list id="offersList"></public-offers-list>
    <advisory-transactions-list id="advTransList"></advisory-transactions-list>
</div>
```

the 2nd directive never loads ... it's just blank. If I remove the first one the 2nd one works.

Any ideas?

Comment: curious, what if you switch the order on the page?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Angular 2 syntax but I would check for errors in console and maybe a missing ; between directive declarations.

Answer (score 0):

This was dumb. These directives are inside a DNN module and what I was trying to do was add these directives as 2 different modules, so the problem was the JS was being registered before the 2nd module was on the page so it wasn't firing.